# Java compare Lottery numbers

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, random

I have an array with 5 random numbers. Like this:

```
int correct[] = {11,23,54,13,5};
```

I have another array, the user's guesses. Like this:

```
int userGuesses[] = {23,5,5,11,50};
```

I want to find how many times the user guessed the lotter numbers correctly, so it cannot repeat.
Like if `userGuesses` has 2 same numbers and user guessed correctly, but `correct[]` has only one value, not two, then the program shouldn't count that.

This is what I have so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    int correct = 0;        
    int good[]  = {1,2,3,4,5};      
    int bad[] = {2,1,5,5,12,3};     

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if(good[i] == bad[i]){
            correct++;
        }
    }       

    System.out.println(correct);        
}
```

Comment: You should have nested loops; The outer runs on the first array, the inner on the second.

Comment: please show me the new version and then i will accept it

Comment: Please do it yourself

Comment: This code looks OK to me. I don't see where is the issue, except that one array is too large.

Comment: Do they need to be in the same position? cause what you have won't count `5` twice. It won't count it once even.

Comment: `good` and `bad` are very confusing names here, ones used above that are better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
int correct = 0;
int good[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // correct answers
int bad[] = {2, 1, 5, 5, 12, 3}; // user guesses

for (int i = 0; i < good.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < bad.length; j++) {
        if (good[i] == bad[j]) {
            correct++;
            break;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(correct);
```

Ok, I wrote a small Java program and it actually works. The actual answer should be 4, because user guessed (assume the 'bad' array is user's guesses) numbers: 1,2,3 and 5, and we do not count it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the values to be tested into a temporary array. Then, change the values in the temporary array when a match is found.

```
int correct = 0;
int[] temp_array = bad.clone();// copy values to be tested into temp array

for(int i = 0; i < good.length; i++)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < bad.length; j++)
   {
      if(good[i] == temp_array[j])// match found
      {
         correct++;// increment correct
         temp_array[j] = -999;// change value to out-of-range 
         break;
      }
   }
}

System.out.println("number correct is " + correct);
```